# infinite pagination doesn't render variables

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to use django infinite pagination, but I'm getting this error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
u'paginate' tag requires a variable name `as` argumnent if the queryset is provided as a nested context variable (prodmatrix.items). You must either pass a direct queryset (e.g. taking advantage of the `with` template tag) or provide a new variable name to store the resulting queryset (e.g. `paginate prodmatrix.items as objects`).
```

This is my template:

```
{% load endless %}

**{% paginate prodmatrix.items %}**
{% for key, values in prodmatrix.items %}
 <li class="span3">
                                                    <div class="product-box">
                                                        <span class="sale_tag"></span>
<p><a href="{% url 'product_detail' slug=values.3.0 %}"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{values.1.0}}" alt="" /></a></p>
<a href="{% url 'product_detail' slug=values.3.0 %}" class="title"><h4>{{ values.0.0 }}</h4></a><br/>
<p class="category"><a href="{% url 'product_detail' slug=values.3.0 %}">{{values.2.0}} {{values.2.1}} {{values.2.2}}</a></p>                                                                                                              </div>
</li>
{% endfor %}
{% show_pages %}
```

This is my view:

```
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        print "login"
        user = request.user
        prods = Product.objects.all()
        i = 0
        print 'numero de produtos ' + str(len(prods))
        prodmatrix = {}
        for prod in prods:
            #                       0             1           2    3
            prodmatrix[str(i)] = [[prod.name], [prod.image], [], [prod.slug]] 
            reviews = Review.objects.filter(product=prod.id) #   ^ this is for tags
            print str(len(reviews))
            if len(reviews) != 0: 
                for review in reviews:
                    rev_alltags = review.tag.all()
                    for tags in rev_alltags[:3]:     #                           
                        print tags.name
                        prodmatrix[str(i)][2].append(tags.name) # append only tags 
            print str(i)
            i = i + 1
        return render(request, 'home.html',{'prodmatrix':prodmatrix})
```

Comment: where is the exact error occuring ?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer. The error occurs in {% paginate entries %}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is occurring because you don't pass the template any variable called entries.

I don't know enough about the lib to give a solution but I believe you will need to do something along the lines of:

```
{% paginate prodmatrix.items %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried your solution, but i'm still getting an error. I updated my question

Comment: It looks like you need to pass it a queryset rather than a dictionary

Comment: Oh, it's impossible for me do this I guess, giving my omplicated string. Is there a way to transform my dictionary in a quesryset?